# Array additions and averages

Tags: c, arrays

So this weeks homework is to: 'Write a program that inputs 6 integers and puts them into an Array. The program
then prints out the following: A list of all Array elements, from 0 to 5 and the sum and
mean value of all elements. NB The mean value of the array elements will not
necessarily be an integer. In order to convert an integer into a real (float) use
casting:
To turn the integer ‘x’ into a float use float(x)
E.g.:
Average = float(sum)/number of elements ;
(In this case the number of elements is 6)'

Not quite sure what I am doing wrong here but my code seems to give back incorrect answers and I can't figure out why.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I am going to fail this module as I have struggled with it since the introduction of functions, etc.

Anyway, here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main() {

   int numArr[5];
   int i, sum = 0;
   float avg;

   printf("\nEnter 6 elements : \n");

   for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
      scanf("%d", &numArr[i]);

   for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      sum = sum + i;
   }
   avg = sum /6;

   printf("The sum is : %d", sum);

   printf("The mean value is : %f", avg);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using integer division. Try `avg = sum /6.0;`

Comment: It is even written in your homework description that you have to cast to float. (even if its `(float)` and not `float()`). Count yourself lucky that people were willing to help even if you ignore the task given...

Comment: LOL in case it wasn't clear Kami, I hadn't realised I had ignored a task. As I say, I am useless at this, despite trying extremely hard. I don't mind admitting I am not intelligent enough in that way to fully understand C programming. I only have another three weeks on this module but I have tried my best the whole way. It just hasn't clicked - but it is not for the want of trying. :)

Answer (score 4):

Your array isn't large enough to hold 6 numbers.

Change

```
   int numArr[5];
```

to

```
   int numArr[6];
```

Currently, you are accessing the array out-of-bunds, resulting in [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

There are couple other problems too:
1) You are not summing the array elements
2) You are doing integer division

Fix it, it'd look like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void) {

   int numArr[6];
   int i, sum = 0;
   float avg;

   printf("\nEnter 6 elements : \n");

   for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
      scanf("%d", &numArr[i]);

   for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      sum = sum + numArr[i]; /* was summing `i` instead of numArr[i] */
   }
   avg = sum /6.0;   /* was doing integer division */
   printf("The sum is : %d", sum);   
   printf("The mean value is : %f", avg); 
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> 'Write a program that inputs **6** integers

```
int numArr[5];
         ^^^^^
```

Change this loop

```
 for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      sum = sum + i;
   }
```

like

```
 for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      sum = sum + numArr[I];
   }
```

And change this statement

```
avg = sum /6;
```

the following way

```
avg = ( float )sum /6;
```

And you forgot to output all elements of the array.

Take into account that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

and you may remove header `<math.h>` because neither declaration is used from this header in your program.

Comment: like the `( float )sum` the question specifically asks to do that

Answer (score 2):

```
sum = sum + i;
```

should be

```
sum = sum + numArr[i];
```

Array elements should be added.

Later

```
avg = sum/6.0
```

Comment: What about the explicit cast to float that was required? And the array is too small, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  sum = sum + numArr[i];
}
avg = (float)sum /6;
```

Notice **numArr[i]**

Answer (score 1):

```
int numArr[5];
```

should be

```
int numArr[6];
```

and

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  sum = sum + i;
}
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  sum = sum + numArr[i];
}
```

and

```
avg = sum /6;
```

should be

```
avg = sum/6.0 //because division of integer by an integer results by integer value. So we divide integer with a float (6.0) value
```